# add list of options in 3 buttons

Tags: mobile, drop-down-list, games

We have mobile game which includes 3 levels (training, public, expert). Each level has specific list of options
[image]

Public and Expert have same 4 options, but Training has extra 5 options, can you help me and tell me how should be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

**Two ideas:**

1. Include the options in a drop-down list that opens on a tap or click for each respective button:

[image]

2. After clicking on one of the buttons, refresh the button list with the second set of options. Include a *back* button so users can navigate back to the original options:

[image]

Comment: can you add images after applying ideas, I did not get your ideas?

Comment: Images added. Very rough ideas.

Comment: Can't hover on a mobile game...

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: instead of hover you can have a tap/click. In every case, you would need one click before the user can see the next set of optinos

Comment: Tap/click would be fine.

Comment: I think option 2 is much better fitting for a game. Option 1 is too "desktop" style looking and selection is harder (fat finger problem).